# map one entity to multiple tables

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Please suppose we have two tables in our database:

**Person**

id, firstname,lastname,titleid(is fk to title.id)

**title**

```
id,name
```

Now we want an entity or java class in spring boot project with its jparepository class:

***Person***

id,firstname,lastname,titleid,**titleName**(may be @transient?!)
in our person entity ,fields id,firstname,lastname,titleid are mapped to person table
 and titleName is mapped to title table.

**first question**: We need to load our entity with a joind query (in one query) but all save, delete queries are as usual targeting person table.How is it possible?
**second question** is how we can write a named query and use it in our jparepository to load only id and firstname and ignore other fields?

Thanks

Comment: Can you share what you have done?

Comment: This is a basic JPA many-to-one relationship. If you need help with that then probably a good idea to read up on some of the fundamentals. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToOne#ManyToOne

Answer (score 0):

Use @OneToOne mapping

so in your person class use

@OneToOne
private Title title;

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `@Table` and `@SecondaryTable` annotations to map both tables to the Person entity. I explained that in more detail in this [written Hibernate Tip](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-tips-how-to-map-an-entity-to-multiple-tables/) and in [this video](https://youtu.be/GBtZ_smkW6E).

This mapping requires 2 simple steps:

1. You need to annotate your entity with JPA’s `@Table` and
   `@SecondaryTable` annotations and provide the names of the first and
   second table as the value of the name parameters. You can also specify the join column between these two tables.
2. You need to annotate each attribute which you want to map to the secondary table
   with a `@Column` annotation and set the name of the secondary table as
   the value of the table attribute.

Based on the tables mentioned in your question, your mapping should look like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
@SecondaryTable(name = "title", pkJoinColumns = @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "titleid", referencedColumnName = "id"))
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    @Column(table = "title", name = "name")
    private String titleName;

    ...
}
```

Comment: `@SecondaryTable` can only be joined on PK. Regardless, despite the phrasing of the question, `@ManyToOne` is what is required here rather than secondary table.

Comment: @Thorben from my understanding SecondaryTable is more desirable when there is one-one mapping between tables.

Comment: @AlanHay also this is a kind of ManyToOne question but there are two points: ManyToOne will issue two queries instead of one query that may be solved with feteched join and I must merge two results into final structure myself. but I want to see if is it possible to have more elegent way for mapping final data. This way rest json replies will be much easier. Thanks

Comment: This is much like a view in database, Maybe it is better to use @Subquery .Maybe I must create PersonView class that extends Person class .I am quite newbie and I am not sure about the best way that this must be done in hibernate and I appreciate all your recommendations